# Is there any javascript charting available that is as good as flex charting?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

I am looking to replace my flex application to support IPad. Are there any good charting components that I can build using javascript to replace my flex charting components? and are they any good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these jquery plugins look promising:

http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

I haven't used any of them so I cannot speak to how good they are.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked on these charting components for JavaScript.

Yui Charts
ejsCharts

Js Charts
http://www.jscharts.com/

Out of these i would recommend you to look on jscharts.